# SQL 2008 Cluster Resource could not bring online

Tags: cluster, sql

I had problem in SQL 2008 R2 cluster resources. When I check the event "An error occurred while processing the log for database 'model'.  If possible, restore from backup. If a backup is not available, it might be necessary to rebuild the log." I could not rebuild the log also.

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2008R2>setup
/quiet /action=rebuilddatabase /instance=MSSQLSERVER /sqlsysadminaccounts=BUILTI
N\Administrators /sapwd=gcc.1234
Microsoft (R) SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup 10.50.2769.00
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The following error occurred:
The setting 'INSTANCE' specified is not recognized.

Error result: -2068578301
Result facility code: 1204
Result error code: 3
```

Please review the summary.txt log for further details

Comment: have you tried with instancename?

Comment: we use the default instance only. So I try with MSSQLSERVER. If any idea please help me.

Comment: Mainstream support for this nearly decade-old software ended three years ago - move on!

Answer (score 0):

I try to rebuild the model database log using the above method. It give the above error. I found the model database and log file from the default drive C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\Templates to the cluster drive. The resources come online. It is working fine now.